# How do I use JavaScript RegExp to replace last occurance of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript variable with string contents having commas (,). How do I replace the last comma (,) with 'and' using RegExp?

```
var band = "John, Paul, George, Ringo";
var beatles = band.replace(<reg-exp>, "and");
console.log(beatles); //outputs "John, Paul, George and Ringo"
```

Comment: Do you only regexp solution or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use greedy `.*` at the start before comma and capture in a group to put it back in replacement:

```
str = str.replace(/^(.*),/, "$1 and");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxEuxM/1)

`.*` will match longest string before matching last `,`.

Another approach is to use negated character class in the end to match 0 or more non-comma characters after comma:

```
str = str.replace(/,\s*([^,]*)$/, " and $1");
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/cxEuxM/2)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Much obliged :-)